# how to store custom tags

Tags: php, parsing

I my application I have custom tags like HTML's `H1` `H2` etc.

The only difference is that the `H2`, should be under `H1` and `H3` under `H2`

example:

```
<H1> lorem ipsum sit dolor ... <H2> something else.... </H2> </H1>
```

I wrote the code to parse the tags and check for validity, now I have to somehow determine their order validity.

How should I saved the tags to easily determine if they are in valid order?

Now I have an array with tags

```
$tags = [];
```

The tags array contains the Tag object
with properties:

```
$order // the order of the tag 1,2,3 etc
$is_close_tag // Boolean, if its a close tag like </h2>
```

I am saving all the tags in one place. I could check by last tag but it's not reliable

```
$last_tag = //
$oder_of_last_tag // lets say 2
$order_current_tag // if 3 valid else invalid
```

I should probably use a `Tree`?

[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD4hb.png)

But I am not sure how to check the validity on Tree.

Comment: *Now I have an array with tags* - what is format of the arrray?